# Finding shift/phase between two datasets

Tags: r, algorithm

I have a large dataset *D* with *(x,y)* coordinates in 2D. I have *almost the same* (with a very few elements missing) dataset *D'* but with a constant shift, *s*. That is, the elements of *D'* are *(x+s, y)*. How do I compute the shift, in an efficient way? Thanks. An r code would be terrific.

Comment: Is the shift s really the same for x and y or should they be different shifts?

Comment: Really sorry, and many thanks for the question. The shift is only in x-direction. Edited my question.

Comment: I was thinking of a dataframe, dat, with x,y, and set_id and then `lm(x ~ y+set_id, data=dat)`

Comment: Sorry. What is `set_id` here? Should I convert the data frame to a set? Also, I think y is from *D'*, right? Thanks.

Comment: Sorting both according to `x` and then take the first point in the sorted `D` whose `y` coordinate equals the `y` coordinate of the first point in `D'` might work, though perhaps could have false positives if multiple points can have the same `y` coordinate. A reproducible example would help this question.

Comment: Are the `y` elements in `D` and `D'` equal?

Comment: Yes, for all the ones that are present in *D'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values of `y` are equal in `D` and `D'` you can perform a join on `y` and a rolling join on `x` with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
D <- data.frame(x = runif(100,1,100), y = runif(100,1,100))
Dprime <- D[sample(1:100,90),]
Dprime$x <- Dprime$x + runif(length(Dprime$x),2.8,3.2)
setDT(Dprime)
setDT(D)
D[,x.original := x]
Dprime[,x.shift := x]
Dprime[D,on=c("y","x"),roll = "nearest"][,.(Shift = x.shift - x.original)][,median(Shift,na.rm=TRUE)]
#[1] 2.997595
```

This addresses the issue of potential duplicate values of `y`. Those values which are missing in `D'` simply get `NA` and are eliminated by `median(x,na.rm=TRUE)`.

For more options on `roll =` that may be better suited to your unique problem, see the roll section of `help(data.table)`.

Comment: I don't quite understand this. OP describes a constant shift from `D` to `D'` but this seems to have many shifts.

Comment: I suspected that there may actually be some random process involved in the OP's shift. This might also help someone years later who finds the question and tries to apply it to their problem. Regardless, it will work even if it really is a constant shift.

Comment: This gives an average shift. If the shift is constant, the above code gives that shift. Anyway, this has to be statistical and depends on how the "nearest" roll is being implemented. But it solves the problem :-)

Comment: What if all the y values are the same? In that edge case, a non-constant shift would be impossible to reverse (unless the magnitude of the shifts is less than the distances between the x-values). For that reason, I am suspicious of a solution that doesn't use a constant shift, although perhaps I need to study on what `roll` does. In any event, it solves OP's problem so +1

Answer (score 0):

Every x value in D' provides an estimate of s  `s = x' - x` so probably your best estimate of s is the average of those.

```
s_est = mean(D'$x - D$x, na.rm = T)
```

Comment: I don't think that this would work. For example, if the very first element of `D` is one of the missing points, then everything is shifted so you would be comparing the `x` coordinate of the points with the shifted `x` coordinate of *other* points. On the other hand, `mean(D'$x) - mean(D$x)` might be a reasonable estimate

Comment: @JohnColeman  I don't think so. This computes each `x' - x` and eliminates the missing ones from the mean.  It does not shift when it encounters missing values.

Comment: You are assuming that the data knows which points are missing. No reason to suppose that they will be marked by `NA`

Comment: Don't you think `x` should be coordinate sorted first for this to work?

Comment: If some of the missing were shifted outliers of the original data (perhaps missing precisely because they are outliers -- who knows?) then a mean-based approach might be problematic. Perhaps `median(D'$x) - median(D$x)` would be more robust.

Comment: I like this approach and the median might be better. Thank you for thinking through this.